# Cómo puedo obtener el último registro de una consulta a MySQL usando Vue.js v2

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js

quiero hacerles una consulta, espero y puedan ayudarme. Estoy trabajando con vue.js v2, tengo una consulta a MySQL con php llamada conexión.php y en dicha consulta me traigo los últimos 1000 registros de la tablet de la BD, tengo otro archivo llamado vue.js en dónde ejecutó la llamada a la consulta de php con este código.

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
all_data:[]
},
 created: function(){
        console.log("Iniciando 
…");
        this.get_datos_sensores();
    },
    methods:{
        get_datos_sensores: function(){
            fetch("./conexion.php")
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(json=>{this.all_data=json.sensores})
        }
    }
});
```

En el HTML tengo una tablet en dónde con la directiva v-for puedo ver los registros, todo ok hasta aquí, pero también quiero tener en una variable aparte el último registro que se guardo para con esa variable poder tomar algunas decisiones en el código y cambiar algunos atributos de las etiquetas HTML como el color del div o el tamaño de la letra ect ect, espero y me hayan entendido y puedan ayudarme. De antemano gracias a todos.

Comment: Porque borraste tu pregunta anterior, donde te estaba tratando de ayudar? te dije como se podia hacer, lo intentaste siquiera????

Comment: Porque me pidieron que especificará bien la pregunta, entonces preferí hacerla más clara y entendible, y no quería que me dijeran que tenía la pregunta doble, discúlpame de verdad me siento apenado por eso. Y gracias por querer ayudarme, si aún lo deseas puedes intentar hacerlo de nuevo. De pena que pena.

Comment: Probaste con una computed property que devuelva el ultimo elemento del array?

Comment: He hecho esto, computed: {
lastSensor(){
const sensorsCount = this.all_data.length;

return sensorsCount > 0 ? this.all_data[sensorsCount - 1] : null;
}
}, y funciona bien ya, pero la consulta a la base de datos la pido de forma Desc lo que quiere decir que en el código me lo vuelve a invertir. Te voy a enviar un link donde tengo el ejercicio online. Te digo que hay cosas que no vienen al caso. Pero céntrate en la tablet y en dónde tengo la lectura de un solo registro.

Comment: y si la pides de forma descente te quedas con el primero y listo.. no entiendo tu problema y menso si lo lograste resolver... porque segun tu comentario, lo resolviste...

Comment: Yo en mi consulta a MySQL pido los datos de forma Desc, y entonces con el código de la propiedad computada si me trae un solo registro y es el último pero como vienen los datos en forma Desc pues entonces me trae el de abajo, te explico el porque lo quiero de esta forma, pues porque en una tablet necesito mostrar primero los últimos registros.

Comment: Sigo sin comprender tu problema.. lo resolviste o no?

Comment: No, no he podido resolverlo pero no importa seguiré viendo los cursos que estoy haciendo por Youtube.

Comment: Actualiza el codigo en tu pregunta. Lo que estas pidiendo no necesita de cursos, solo de que entiendas lo que tenes ahi...